# Git clone on server and auto pull

Tags: git, github

i have an existing git repository i want to clone it on google compute server.
the first thing i need to do is getting a clone on server of existing repo, but when i run the git clone it shows this error

```
#git clone ssh://git@github.com:USER/REPO.git .
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/PATH/public_html/.git/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:USER: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

can somebody help me resolve this issue and after i get a clone i need it to auto pull when i push changes to github

PS: i have also tried to init a new repository

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not added your ssh key to the server. After you add it, the server will ask you to accept the host as a recognised host for all future requests. Until then `github.com` will be an unrecognised host.

Comment: i am trying to clone on my server using ssh on terminal... y would i need to add my ssh keys? can u tell me how to do that? btw i have added server ssh keys to github